# Heroku: Push cloned to another app

Tags: git, heroku

I cloned an app using:
`heroku git:clone -a my-app-01`
Then I created another app:
`heroku create`
then, creates the app named `my-app-02`
I want to push my cloned app to `my-app-02` using `git push heroku master`
But when I `git remote -v`, it is still referring to the old app `my-app-01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [`heroku create my-app-02`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/creating-apps) within the `my-app-01` folder (cloned repo), a `git remote -v` would reflect the cloned repo upstream URL.

It is best to not create a nested Git repo, but [track my-app-02 in Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#tracking-your-app-in-git) from another folder than `my-app-01`. That way, both Git repositories are different (not nested).